# Does a class property auto initialization if I access that objects properties?

Tags: c#, class, properties

When an object hold another object as a property and that property is by default null. Will that property be initialized if its own property's get accessed by code?

```
public User {
    private _obj = null;
    public Obj SomeObject {
        get { return _obj ?? (_obj = new Obj()); }
        set { _obj = value; }
    }

    public User() {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Code Being used.

```
User user = new User();

int x = user.SomeObject.SomeIntValue;
```

Would this initiate a new version of SomeObject if it was null?

-- Edit --
Applied @Kjartan suggestion to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will indeed work. The first time the property will get accessed, _obj will be filled with the new instance (since it was null before). Next calls, you will return the same Obj instance that was initialized the first time.

This is a common way for creating some sort of "lazy-loading".

Comment: There also is a class for lazy initialization [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx)

Comment: Thanks so much for confirming :D

Answer (score 2):

Should work. And as a side-note, just for brevity you could replace this:

```
 get {
      if(_obj == null)
           _obj = new Obj();
      return _obj;
 }
```

...with this:

```
  get { return _obj ?? (_obj = new Obj()); }
```